# What will be the order of differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

What will be the order of given differential equations. 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y }{\mathrm{d} x^2}+\frac{\mathrm{d}y }{\mathrm{d} x}+\int y\ dx=0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  ...(1)$$
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y }{\mathrm{d} x^2}+\frac{\mathrm{d}y }{\mathrm{d} x}+\int f(x)\ dx=0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ ...(2)$$

My teacher said that in first equation we will differentiate it one more time. **So the order is 3** 
But in second differential equation there is no need to differentiate it **so the order is 2**

**My doubt** In 2nd differential equation if we integrate $f(x)$ then an arbitrary constant term will appear and we need to remove this constant so differentiate it one more time. **Therefore the order will be 3**. But its not.

**Can anyone explain the exact reason behind these two differential equation.**

Note:- I am only intersted in order.

Comment: You don't need to get rid of the constant term in equation (2). As it is, you have a second order linear differential equation because the term $\int f(x)dx$ is only a function of the independent variable (although, you could argue what you really get is a set of 2nd order equations, one for each value of C).

Comment: @TobErnack why cant we apply same logic to first equation i.e. in first equation its soln will be $y=g(x)$ type and in this case this the order will be 2 of equation 1. Your help means a lot for me. Please explain it briefly.

Comment: $f(x)$ isn't necessarily dependent on $y$, but your $g(x)=y$ is obviously dependent on y. $\int f(x) dx$ is just a function of the independent variable $x$.

Comment: as if (1) resembles an integral equation for $y$ obtained one time  integrating DE. To recover DE we need to differentiate it. But (2) is not so. If you look the definition, either arbitrary or certain constants do not affect the order of DE.

Comment: Just look at ''the highest derivative term appearing in the equation'' for unknown function $y$.